# Reactive UI Merging Observables to a ObservableAsPropertyHelper

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am trying to merge several `Observable`s on a couple of `ReactiveList`s to create an `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`.

```
public class Model : ReactiveObject {
    ReactiveList<int> IngredientsEntities;
    // ...
    public int CostOfIngredients(...) { ... }
}

public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject {

    public Model Promotion;

    private ReactiveList<int> ingredientsQuantities;
    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> cost;

    public Dictionary<..., ...> Ingredients;

    public int Cost {
        get { return cost.Value; }
    }

    public ViewModel() {
        // ...

        var ingredientsObservables = new[]
        {
            ingredientsQuantities.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
            ingredientsQuantities.ShouldReset.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
            Promotion.IngredientsEntities.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
            Promotion.IngredientsEntities.ShouldReset.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
        };
        Observable.Merge(ingredientsObservables)
            .Select(_ => promotion.CostOfIngredients(Ingredients))
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.Cost, out cost);

        Observable.Merge(ingredientsObservables)
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                this.Log().Info("Ingredients change detected");
            });

    }
}
```

The log message fires, but the `CostOfIngredients` never gets called, and `cost` remains `null`. Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:

I modified `ViewModel` and this now works:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject {
    private int cost;
    public int Cost {
        get { return cost; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref cost, value); }
    }

    // ...

   public ViewModel() {
        // ...
        var ingredientsObservables = new[]
            {
                ingredientsQuantities.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
                ingredientsQuantities.ShouldReset.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
                Promotion.IngredientsEntities.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
                Promotion.IngredientsEntities.ShouldReset.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
            };
            Observable.Merge(ingredientsObservables)
                .Subscribe(_ => Cost = promotion.CostOfIngredients(Ingredients));

   }
}
```

My understanding is that `Select(_ => Unit.Default)` creates an `Observable` for `Unit.Default` that never changes, thus never invoking any further `Select`s.

Comment: wondering whether converting the observables into IObservables<> always w/ the same value that that never changes cause it never changes value and thus never fires.

Comment: When you say that "cost remains null" do you mean that the ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> is null? In that case, it is as if the ToProperty never worked.

Comment: I believe that the ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> object is lazy: it won't actually subscribe and get things setup and working unless your view subscribes to it (does a Bind to the Cost). Did that happen? If it did, then something else is going on.

Comment: Finally, the "select(_ => Unit.Default) will "issue" a Unit every single time a new element is called. There is no logic behind it... to get the behavior you describe (it doesn't send anything if it is the same) see the DistinctUntilChanged() and Distinct() functions - which are very useful!

Comment: I meant that the `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` is not null, but that its `.Value` is null. Yes, there is a `OneWayBind` to `Cost`.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is your use of `ItemChanged` - this only fires if you have item tracking enabled, and only when an item in your collection changes (i.e. `myList[3].SomeProperty = "bar";`). You probably want `Changed`, which will cover everything.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did some permutation with item tracking enabled explicitly. And my list only changes in terms of its property -- nothing gets added or removed. Still, that did not work.